# How can I determine what is wrong with my laptop screen?

Tags: hardware-failure, laptop-display

In order to obtain a normal level of brightness/contrast I have to slightly twist the screen, otherwise an array of GPU artifacts tend to appear on the screen, sometimes. I know, this sounds insane.

**Symptoms**:

- GPU artifacts tend to appear if a black window (e.g. a terminal) is next to a white window, or in other high contrast situations; and
- I need to apply force to the edges of my laptop screen to achieve proper contrast

---

- No pressure applied to corners:

[image: No pressure applied to corners]

- Applying pressure to corners:

[image: Applying pressure to corners]

---

Since I carry my laptop around with me in a laptop bag, there's a chance that the screen was pressed in, or damaged slightly, but I honestly have no idea how to diagnose this. Perhaps there is a chance that a ribbon cable is damaged?

There is a chance that the GPU artifacts have been introduced as a result of my inability to install a graphics driver, but I'm not sure.  It looks like neither the proprietary or open source drivers work for my laptop any more, even though they worked before I re-installed Arch Linux a few weeks ago.

Comment: For brevity, here is a video which demonstrates the change in contrast when pressure is applied https://gfycat.com/EmotionalTatteredBinturong (I was not able to add it to my post)

Answer (score 0):

Applying physical force to the monitor will not affect the GPU. There is a problem with the monitor. The easiest way to verify is to connect an external monitor. As for solving the monitor problem, the following are options, in order of preference: Warranty repair, buy a new laptop, duct tape, take it apart and see if you can fix it. I advise against the last option unless there is nothing else you can do - laptop monitors are easily damaged during amateur repair.